# No visible @interface for 'RBQFetchedResultsController' declares the selector 'updateFetchRequest:sectionNameKeyPath:andPeformFetch:'

Tags: objective-c, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm a new ios (objective C), I searching about Realm, but when I do same tutorial on Realm, i have this error, i tried to fix them many times.

thanks!

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.**strong text**com/jKQD9.png

Comment: The link you write is unreachable. Can you please update error messages to your post instead screenshot? Also, it's very unclear what you do. How did you setup Realm? What is the tutorial did you read?

Comment: thank you! this is my tutorial: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation
i can't run my project

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation) (Link https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation)
2. After that RUN project

[image: Run]